# Is there an official plot explanation for the movie U.F.O. (2012)?

Tags: ufo-movie

I watched the movie [U.F.O.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.F.O._%282012_film) from 2012 with Jean-Claude Van Damme.

Expecting a low budget, low quality sci-fi b-movie, I was surprised by the first half of the movie, as I found it quite entertaining. In the second half the open questions stacked up, and were not answered, at least not as far as I understood.

I had the same problem with the movie Donnie Darko, and found a complete "official" web page explaining the plot and the background time travel theories that were intentionally not explained in the movie itself.

Is there any kind of official explanation of the plot of U.F.O, too?

Here are some things I don't understand:

- Were there two alien factions at war with each other in the end?
- Why do the disguised aliens have marks to identify them?
- Why are there humans (hobo, little girl) who know about this, and how can they identify the aliens even without seeing the mark?

Is it just a bad story full of plot holes? Or is there a plan behind it? (The fights between the aliens in the end seems to hint to that.)

So, the question is: is there an official explanation of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dominic Burns ,the screenwriter of U.F.O (AKA Alien Uprising) has confirmed some additional detail about the film on [twitter](https://twitter.com/DominicBurns).

[image]

Based on his response, we can deduce the answers to at least a few of your questions...

- **Were there two alien factions at war with each other in the end?**

*Yes, and more than that, we can reasonably deduce that there were multiple species of aliens. The attack on Earth was merely one front in their ongoing war.*

- **Why do the disguised aliens have marks to identify them?**

*It might seem non-intuitive, but these are soldiers fighting a war. It seems reasonable that they would have some way of distinguishing themselves (and enemies) from mere humans.*

---

As to whether there is any canonical source that exists to explain the plot points, sadly the answer is **no**. From what I can tell, the film never even had an official website. Once the film was launched, the actors and crew seem to have done almost no interviews either, presumably because of the poor critical reception.

Answer (score 1):

Heads up, this movie was also released under the Title "Alien Uprising."  I live in the States and that's how it is listed in my Netflix.

This movie is about a shadow invasion/conquering of earth by Extraterrestrials, where their goal is to minimize collateral damage. I.e. they don't want to destroy the world, only conquer it and rule over us.  To this end, they disrupt communication networks to prevent organized resistance.  Furthermore, a major threat to causing collateral damage is human panic. No communication prevents wide-spread panic.

The story follows 4 friends Michael, Vincent, Robin, and Robin's girl, Dana, as they go clubbing, one picks up a girl, and the next day they wake up to find power, phones, radio, and TV all not working.  On the second day, large flying saucers arrive over the cities.

Carrie (Bianca Bree Van Damme) is the girl Michael (Sean Brosnan) picks up at the club at the beginning of the movie.

She also is an alien/extraterrestrial visitor.

The Aliens have been living secretly among us.

The soldier (also an alien) guarding the Chemist shop moves to attack and kill the girl who knew he had "the purple mark," presumably to conceal the alien existence.
Carrie attacks him, which could lead us to believe there are two factions.

The friends eventually wind up at George's (Michael's uncle) place (Jean Claude Van Damme).  George is one of those ex-military, knows top secret stuff kind of guys.

At the end of the movie, the flying saucers (cylindrical ships) are locked into a space battle with pyramid shaped ships.  We also the see soldier who was guarding the Chemist shop back to life.  (Or at least a copy of him.)

So the way I see it, there are two possible endings here, which are ambiguous.

(Ending 1) 
When Carrie killed the Soldier in the Chemist shop, she knew she wasn't truly killing him.  So when the fighter ships are destroyed, the aliens are destroying ships, but they are not losing any life as they stage this battle for our benefit.  The Aliens staged a fake war so that humans could come out of the event feeling like they had won, when in fact, the aliens had quietly assumed power.

(Ending 2) 
The aliens are trying to do a shadow take over, but humans have built a massive fleet of space ships, copying technology that has crashed on earth over the years.  As the movie concludes, the human space fleet is moving into higher orbit around earth, taking the fight to the enemy.

I think Ending 1 is much more consistent with the theme of the movie focusing on mankind's capacity for violence, almost as if the movie is passing judgment on mankind and pronouncing him unworthy to continue living.

I think you could probably come up with some other theories that fit the movie as well.  It definitely is not the most clear ending in movie history.

Comment: The question was asking for an *official* plot explanation.

Comment: Thank you. The different title is an important information.